# How to check Array of strings contains a particular string?

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, collections, attributes

I'm using .NET 2.0
I have a large array of string.
I want to check whether a particular string is there in the array or not,
I'm not sure, whether following code is optimized or I need to make it more optimized.
please guide.

```
string []test_arr= new string[]{"key1","key2","key3"};
Boolean testCondition = (new List<string>(test_arr)).Contains("key3");
```

I also wants to know more about

1. .NET Generics
2. .NET Attributes
3. .NET Reflections

is there any good reference or book, that someone has already refer then help me out !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
string []test_arr= new string[]{"key1","key2","key3"};
bool testCondition = Array.Exists
(
    test_arr,
    delegate(string s) { return s == "key3";}
);
```

Comment: Thanks Luke, was writing from memory. I have corrected the code.

Comment: You probably mixed Lamda and delegate notation ;).

Answer (score 2):

If its possible you could sort your array (using static [Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort.aspx) method) and then use [Array.BinarySearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.binarysearch.aspx)

Alternatively you need to use a more optimised data structure for your strings.

Answer (score 2):

My answer very similar to Matt Howells.
But I'm suggesting to use [StringComparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx)

```
Array.Exists<string>(stringsArray,
                delegate(string match)
                {
                    return match.Equals("key", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

In the .NET Framework version 2.0, the Array class implements the System.Collections.Generic.IList, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection, and System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable generic interfaces.

Hence you can do the following:

```
string[] test_arr = new string[]{"key1","key2","key3"};
Boolean testCondition = ((IList<string>)test_arr).Contains("key3");
```

Answer (score 1):

List is O(n), SortedList is O(log n)

Answer (score 1):

In your sample the biggest overhead will probably be the creation of the List, but that may be part of the demonstration.

Starting from array, the following will probably be faster:

```
int x = Array.IndexOf<string>(test_arr, "key3");
bool testCondition = x >= 0;
```

But if you have the option, it would be more efficient to use a `HashSet<string>` to store them in the first place. HashSet can check the existence of an element in O(1).

Regarding your other questions, they have already been asked on SO, use the search option, for instance with "C# books"

Answer (score 1):

abouot your larga array of string: 
there is no optimized way as long as you use an array (you have to start at the first element and go through each until you find it - or go through the whole array if you dont) - this gives you a worst case time of O(n) (O notation gives the time a program needs to accomplish something).

Since you want to optimize for search I suggest you use a hashtable or tree instead (depending on how large your dataset is). This will greatly reduce the time you need to check